# Angularjs select2 dropdown validation

Tags: angularjs

I am using select2 plugin.  I want to show an error to the user whenever the user forget to select the dropdown value on submit. But what happen means it shows the error message correctly, but the error message is showing after the dropdown value is selected.

My code is,

```
<select name="books" ng-model="books" wb-select2 initial-select-key="authour" target-id="books" ng-options="book.authour for book in books track by book.id" class="select2" required="true">
```

Comment: you should call the error message in submit click

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in a form tag and use form validations on it like below:

**HTML:**

```
<form name="formName" ng-submit="formName.$valid&&accountSave()" novalidate>
    <select name="books" ng-model="books" wb-select2 initial-select-key="authour" target-id="books" ng-options="book.authour for book in books track by book.id" class="select2" required="true">
    <p ng-if="formName.$submitted&&formName.books.$error.required" class="error">Books is required</p>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.accountSave=function(){
  //post form details to server
}
```

**For more info**: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form